# What does Babel do to let me use any name to import a node module that exports a function

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-modules

An example will make my question clearer, say I want to import [debug module](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug) to my vuejs codes

Debug module export `createDebug` function like this,

```
module.exports = require('./browser.js');
...
exports = module.exports = createDebug.debug = createDebug['default'] = createDebug;

function createDebug(namespace) { ... }
```

When I use `import` to import debug module, I can give it any name I want, like

```
import debug from 'debug' // or any name I want, e.g
import debugjs from 'debug'
```

I understand if `export default` anonymous function I can then import it with any name I want, but this is not the case here.

So why can I use any name to import it?

---------------- update -----------------

One takeaway from the answer is that `import "any name"` work for [both](http://es6.ruanyifeng.com/#docs/module#export-default-%E5%91%BD%E4%BB%A4) default export anonymous function and named function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but this is not the case here.

It kind of is. You are trying to import a module that has no ES6 exports. You are trying to import a CommonJS module. So Babel has to make a decision how to handle that case.

There are two common ways to export something from a CommonJS module:

- Assign a property to `exports` (or `module.expoets`), for example `exports.answer = 42;`
- Overwrite the value of `module.exports`, e.g. `module.exports = 42;`.

In the second case you end up exporting only a single value from the module.  That's basically what a default export is (since there can only be one) and that's what you are doing in your code.

So in other words, when importing a CommonJS module via ES6 `import` statements, then the value of `module.exports` is used as the default export value.

We can confirm that by looking at [how Babel converts the code](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=JYWwDg9gTgLgBAMwhRUIjgcgEYEMqYDcQA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=):

```
// import foo from 'bar'; becomes
var _bar = require('bar');

var _bar2 = _interopRequireDefault(_bar);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) {
  return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj };
  //                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Comment: So import "any name" works for both default export anonymous function and named function. Thanks!

Comment: It works for any value. `export default <whatever>;` (or `module.exports = <whatever>;`) allows the *importer* to specify the name they want to assign the value to. Consequently it doesn't matter whether the function is named or not if works the same for any value.